# Form broken after changing it to a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this Rails app, Users can write Stories and add them to Collections. As they write a Story, users can add it to an existing Collection or create a new one while in the stories/new.html.erb view through a modal.

It looks like this currently

routes.rb

```
resources :users
resources :collections
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Collection.new do |f| %>
```

collections controller

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @user = current_user # or however
  @collection = Collection.new
end

  def show
    @collection = Collection.friendly.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def create
    @collection = current_user.collections.build(collection_params)
    if @collection.save
      render json: @collection
    else
      render json: {errors: @collection.errors.full_messages}
    end
  end

  private

  def collection_params
    params.require(:collection).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

stories controller

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @story = Story.new
    authorize @story
  end
end
```

Now I want to nest the routes such that collections belong to users as such

```
resources :users do
   resources :collections
```

However, that causes an error on this line

```
 <%= form_for Collection.new do |f| %>
```

and it no longer works. How do fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After nesting the resources, the collection routes changed

If earlier a route was

```
/collections/24
```

Now it becomes

```
/users/1/collections/24
```

So you have to change the form_for method. You need to add the resource its nested with which in this case should be

```
<%= form_for [@user,@collection] do |f| %>
    #your code here
<% end %>
```

Also you have to add associations to both models, i.e User `has_many :collections` and Collection `belongs_to :user`

In your controller, first user has to be instantiated, then collection will be created:

```
@user = current_user #The parameter can be named anything
@collection = Collection.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your the form object about the new routing schema.

Also don't write `Model.new` directly into your form.

When nesting routes like this, we're making assumptions about users and collections, that the user already exists.

You should instantiate your resources (the existing user and new collection) in your `new` action.

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # since nested
  @collection = Collection.new
end

<% form_for [@user, @collection] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still getting this error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" for the line  <%= form_for [@user, @collection] do |f| %>

Comment: You need to make sure both `@user` and `@collection` are defined

Comment: In this case where should I define them? I have already done so in the controller as far as I know. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with the relevant controllers actions. I suppose the new action you provided is meant to go in stories controller instead?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you're fetching and making collections for `current_user` I wouldn't bother nesting. But say you're passing the user id through the new link `/users/1/collections/new`, then you should probably use that. Also add `debugger` to your controller to step through or just add `puts @user.inspect` and `puts @collection.inspect` to ensure they are what you want.